# How to create an animated shining star with halo and rays in Cycles, Blender 3.0

Tags: lighting

Good morning!

I want to create a shining star with glow and light rays. I've tried using emission and glare in cycles but without much luck. And no sun rays yet. It looks like previous Blender versions had Halo which was perfect. Now, not. I've included an image of what I am shooting for.

Thank you for sharing your time, energy and expertise! It is much appreciated.

[image: Shining Star Example]

Comment: You can combine several *Glare* nodes. One with mode *Streaks* and one with mode *Fog Glow* for example to get the inner glow effect plus the streaks. But the number of streaks is limited to 16 and the streaks have all the same length. Of course, you can mix two *Glare (Streak)* nodes to get 32 streaks but it will have not this variation in the length of the streaks. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBMZn.jpg (emission sphere + glare nodes in compositor)

Comment: Good morning and thank you. Not only is it a brilliant idea, it is beautiful. I will play with it. I've used Glare and the compositor a bit but not much. I'm new :-)

I'm not sure if I can animate in the compositor or not. That I will have to look into.

Thank you again for your time and expertise.

Comment: Research Update: Someone mentioned a product on Blender Market that they thought might work. I bought/tried it: Flared-Lens-Flare.

Presale, dev kindly tried to educate me (I'm new to Blender) but I misunderstood what a lens flare is. It applies to camera lens! Not an emission/bloom/glare aspect of my object. Which apparently is what I need. Still, Flared looks lovely. Dev helpful. I will use it later. 

So back to the drawing board. Create animated emission like the image attached. Will continue to research and post updates. (PS. I'm not dev nor get commission. I just loved the add-on)